# Rest web service return multiple responses

Tags: c#, rest

I have a rest web service that when supplied with the correct parameters would return me two results that is either success status or failure status now i am supposed to add the reason for failure and hence i need to get the output in two seperate lines that is in one line failure stataus and other line reason for failure all in all i need two responses for my failure i tried it but i am only able to return only one response how shall ido it can anyone help me regarding this.

```
   upd_status = "1" //failure
   return err_msg = "INVALID USERNAME/PASSWORD";
```

here I want to return upd_status too how can i do it

Answer (score 1):

create a class like

```
class ResponseData
{
     public string responseCode {get; set;}
     public string response {get; set;}
     public string responseStatus {get; set;}
}
```

create a obj of this object and assign all values to variables and return this object so you can get multiple response data as you want

Answer (score 0):

make a List< string> and add both values to the list. Then simply return Json(list).. It would return a JSON array with both values as follows:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add(upd_status);
list.Add(err_msg);

return Json(list.ToArray());
```

Comment: this solution seems good can u provide an example plz or a short code

Comment: json does notn exist in current context i have added the required namespace but also i am getting the error

Comment: can u show your complete method? what is the return type?